# how to manage read and unread notification in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm working in react js and I want to develop notifications component which related to the  account related activities. I have to display all the account related activities in the notifications list and sort them as a `read` and `unread` notifications.

so the my question is how to manage read and unread notification in react/ next js ?

Do I need to make it state or session storage ?

consider this is my notification list :

```
const notificationArray = [
  { id: 1, msg: 'one' },
  { id: 2, msg: 'two' },
  { id: 3, msg: 'three' },
  { id: 4, msg: 'four' },
  { id: 5, msg: 'five' },
];
```

And in the below list I have received one new notification :

```
const notificationArray = [
  { id: 1, msg: 'one' },
  { id: 2, msg: 'two' },
  { id: 3, msg: 'three' },
  { id: 4, msg: 'four' },
  { id: 5, msg: 'five' },
  { id: 6, msg: 'six' }
];
```

Comment: you can add a boolean variable in each index of your array like, `{ id : 1 , msg : 'one', read : false}` , then if your notification was rendered on UI or clicked by the users, you can change the property of `read : true` This way you can keep track of what is read and what is not.

Answer (score 1):

If your notification data comes from database you need to add a new property that indicates weather it is read or no
And then you can use just State no need for session whenever the user read the notification you update the list in client side and async tell the back end that the notification has been read

data will look like this:

```
[{id:1,msg:'msg',read:false}.....]
```

and client side code will look like this:

```
const [notifs,setNotifs] = useState()
function setRead(id){
  for (var i in notifs) {
     if (notifs[i].id === id) {
        notifs[i].read = true;
        break;
     }
   }
  setNotifs(notifs)
callYourBackEnd(id,readStatus) // here just call your api service or something and send to it id of the notif and the read status 'true of false' which is probably true

}
//maping the notifs list here and pass the id to setRead
notifs?.map(notif=> <NotifComonent onClick={e=>setRead(notif.id)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to manage read and unread notification in react/ next js ?

After creating a new notification, in server-side or client-side, add a property in notification called `hasRead` or something, which is by default set to false. Then whenever the user read the notification, set that property to true.

> Do I need to make it state or session storage ?

It depends what type of app you are creating. For a real world app, the data probably comes from a database. There are multiple options for storing user data - databases, local storage, session storage, memory. Choose whatever suits your need.

Answer (score 0):

do it like this

```
const notificationArray = [
  { id: 1, msg: 'one' , read: true },
  { id: 2, msg: 'two' , read: true},
  { id: 3, msg: 'three', read: true },
  { id: 4, msg: 'four' , read: true},
  { id: 5, msg: 'five' , read: true },
  { id: 6, msg: 'six' , read: false }
];
```

when the message is received you make a notification to the user
then you store this data in server or in localStorage